# rails4.2 heroku cloudfront serving static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, amazon-cloudfront

I have a rails4 app deployed on heroku and using cloudfront as CDN.

Everything works fine in development. In production only the things in the app/assets are served properly, the images in the public folder can't be found.

What should I do to make the public folder assets work? I'd like to serve them from CDN as well if possible, but I'm open to any working solution

Current settings:

production.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present? #enabled by heroku default settings
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'mycode.cloudfront.net'
config.font_assets.origin = '*'
```

gemfile

```
# I'm NOT using asset_sync gem
gem 'font_assets', '~> 0.1.12' #this is needed to make googlefonts work
gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3', group :production
```

UPDATE:

working heroku logs

```
2016-01-25T19:00:24.624690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/500.html" host=appfaskyn.herokuapp.com request_id=d1a637be-b539-429a-9fcd-5f4d0025b562 fwd="50.250.214.91" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=48
2016-01-25T19:00:24.794605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/thirdlogo.png" host=appfaskyn.herokuapp.com request_id=41b8aa45-8e70-43ef-af53-b4e0ad44ec8b fwd="50.250.214.91" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=48
```

UPDATE2:

Realized that it works w/ certain routes.
So if I hit app/dsfd then it finds the pic with `path="/dsfd"`
but if I hit app/users/2 (user does not exist anymore, so should be the same page does not exist error) then  `path="/users/2"` can't find the pic.

log if found:

```
2016-01-29T18:56:14.377420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dsfd" host=www.faskyn.com request_id=76e1c73d-dd22-446f-89b4-096dcbae6f6c fwd="64.245.0.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=404 bytes=840
2016-01-29T18:56:14.320423+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=76e1c73d-dd22-446f-89b4-096dcbae6f6c wait=0ms timeout=20000ms state=ready
2016-01-29T18:56:14.320609+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=76e1c73d-dd22-446f-89b4-096dcbae6f6c wait=0ms timeout=20000ms service=1ms state=active
2016-01-29T18:56:14.324730+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/dsfd" for 64.245.0.218 at 2016-01-29 18:56:14 +0000
2016-01-29T18:56:14.331095+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-29T18:56:14.331099+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fddf"):
2016-01-29T18:56:14.331100+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispa
```

logs if not found:

```
Processing by UsersController#show as PNG
2016-01-29T18:49:20.952915+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"thirdlogo"}
2016-01-29T18:49:20.959096+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-01-29T18:49:20.963937+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)
2016-01-29T18:49:20.985358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/thirdlogo.png" host=www.faskyn.com request_id=e913ee09-3837-4da6-8e7f-f3eebc15de00 fwd="64.245.0.218" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms status=404 bytes=840
```

Comment: Basically you shouldn't serve files from public if it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: 404/422/500 html are placed there by default. I only have those in the public folder, and wanna show image when sby gets on those pages.

Comment: I understand. What is your value of `ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES']`?

Comment: did not set manually. the deafult on heroku is enabled

Comment: which means that `config.serve_static_files = false`...

Comment: it's default enabled, I checked it out; heroku config:get RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES returns enabled

Comment: So if you go to `yourcomain.com/500.html` what do you get in `production.log`?

Comment: I had taken the pic out from the code, cuz looks shitty when the browser can't find the image. Now after you asking for the log I put it back and it's working. I don't really get it. The code exactly the same as it was. Maybe I had to wait for some reason to have it working. Anyway, can you see something from the working log> ( I updated the question.) This is what I should have with CDN?

Comment: Michal is happening again. Updated my question.

Comment: You're requesting `/users/thirdlogo.png` which routes to `users_controller` what do you expect to happen?!

Comment: I know, but it can display the error page properly (which is in public folder) except the image. So I'd like to know how can I make it work for the image as well.